# why I could use HBase without starting Hadoop/HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to HBase, recently I installed HBase and tried to start it on my Mac. Everything is fine and I could play with HBase. In some articles, it said I should start Hadoop first when using HBase, I am wondering if this prerequisite changed?

Comment: Are you able to run the HBase web ui? I also installed HBase on a Mac and can play with HBase via the shell. However, I can't access HBase through the web ui at http://localhost:16010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is not a hard requirement for HBase unless you are running fully distributed which you are not.  Running on a single node like you are you can use the local filesystem.  See [HBase run modes: Standalone and Distributed](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#standalone_dist) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your local filesystem (the `file://` URI) is Hadoop-compatible. Hbase requires a *Hadoop compatible storage layer*, but that does not mean that it must literally be HDFS.

HDFS will simply provide scalability and reliability